# example for low layer fatfs for spi flash

Tags: stm32, spi, flash-memory, fatfs

I want to launch the FatFs file system library for SPI FLASH memory.

I need an example or a guide to port the low layer of the this library.

FatFs Link:
http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html

SPI FLASH Part number: **W25Q64FV**

MCU Type: **STM32F107VC**

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the functions named on that page. These are:

- `disk_status` - Get device status
- `disk_initialize` - Initialize device
- `disk_read` - Read sector(s)
- `disk_write` - Write sector(s)
- `disk_ioctl` - Control device dependent functions
- `get_fattime` - Get current time

How you do it doesn't matter. There just needs to be a definition of these functions provided by you for these already declared and used functions inside the library.

You'll need to set the fattime to static for the most basic version of this. And the functions `disk_status` `disk_ioctl` `get_fattime` can do nothing and just return `RES_OK`